# Comparing different vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, comparison

I am trying to write some code to compare vectors element by element. So say I had three int vectors:

v1 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

v2 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

v3 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

And I wanted to compare the three element by element - so compare v1[0], v2[0], v3[0]. Then v1[1], v2[1], v3[1] and so on. How is this possible in C++? I can't find anywhere on google that seems to be able to do this. Maybe I should just make the vectors a 2d array and work on the cols?

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: What do you need to do after a three-way comparison? Comparing is easy - `std::vector`s provide an implementation of `<` operator.

Comment: Take a guess, based on your knowledge of how other things in the language are normally compared.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare vectors"? Does order matter? And why does a simple for loop not accomplish what you need?

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question. Compare them element by element, first element 0, then element 1, etc.

Comment: My issue is I don't know in advance how many vectors in advance to compare, but I'd like to know for each position, if the values in all the vectors are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool vectors_are_equal = false;
const unsigned int size = v1.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  if ((v1[i] == v2[i]) && (v2[i] == v3[i]))
  {
     continue;
  }
  else
  {
     break;
  }
}
if (i >= size)
{
  vectors_are_equal == true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Matthews, your code does not compile. Here is working example:

```
bool areVectorsEqual(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2, const std::vector<int>& v3) {
  if (v1.size() != v2.size() || v2.size() != v3.size()) {
    return false;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
    if (v1[i] != v2[i] || v2[i] != v3[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

You could improve this allowing n number of vectors to be compared.